# Sending a WhatsApp message with Google Assisten while phone is locked

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, lock-screens, google-assistant

Currently, when my phone is locked, I can use the Google Assistant to send a regular text message. This does work.
When trying to use a WhatsApp message, though, the Assistant tells me that I need to unlock the phone. Well, when I am on the motorcycle, this is a problem.
Do I have a bad configuration or is this not possible?

How can I send a WhatsApp message using Google Assistant while my phone is locked